# Sumar ingresos de Prompt en un bucle

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

Una pregunta bastante básica pero no encuentro cómo resolver aún. Tengo que sumar los multiples ingresos obtenidos de un prompt en las distintas iteraciones de un bucle. Cómo registro estos valores para obter luego el total?

```
let cantidadVentas=prompt("Ingrese cantidad de ventas: ");

for(let i=0; i<cantidadVentas; i++){
    let ventaReal=i;
    let valorNeto=parseInt(prompt("Ingrese valor neto de la venta " + (++ventaReal) + ":"));
    if (valorNeto<0){
        break;
    }

    if(isNaN(valorNeto)){
        continue;
    }

    let porcentajeIva=0.215;
    let valorIva=valorNeto*porcentajeIva;
    let valorTotal=(valorNeto+valorIva);

    alert("Valor IVA " + valorIva);

    let resumen=confirm("Querés ver el resumen de tu compra? ");

    if(resumen){
        alert("Importe sin IVA: " + valorNeto + " ARS\nMonto IVA: " + valorIva + " ARS\nTOTAL: " + valorTotal + " ARS")
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenidx a SOes! Recuerda siempre incluir una breve descripción de _cuál es el problema con tu código_. Está muy bien que lo hayas añadido como texto para que otros prueben, pero la respuesta siempre llegará muchísimo más rápido si dices qué es lo que no funciona, con qué datos de entrada probaste, qué debería salir y qué está saliendo.

Answer (score 0):

Acomode un poco tu codigo, saque a `valorNeto` para que puedas usarlo dentro y fuera del for, y lo uso como acumulador, cada vez que pida los números ira sumándole al `valorNeto` , a su vez complete el for solo para el ingreso, y luego recién haces el proceso de venta.

**EDIT**
Puse como numero de para en el for a 5, pero tu recibes `cantidadVentas`, solo tendrías que ponerla de nuevo.

```js
var valorNeto = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  let ventaReal = i;
  valorNeto = valorNeto + parseInt(prompt("Ingrese valor neto de la venta "     + (++ventaReal) + ":"));
  if (valorNeto < 0) {
    break;
  }

  if (isNaN(valorNeto)) {
    continue;
  }
}
let porcentajeIva = 0.215;
let valorIva = valorNeto * porcentajeIva;
let valorTotal = (valorNeto + valorIva);

alert("Valor IVA " + valorIva);

let resumen = confirm("Querés ver el resumen de tu compra? ");

if (resumen) {
  alert("Importe sin IVA: " + valorNeto + " ARS\nMonto IVA: " + valorIva + " ARS\nTOTAL: " + valorTotal + " ARS")
}
```